# Finding the maximum of a function on a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I want to find the maximum of $f(x,y) = x^ae^{-x}y^be^{-y}$ on the triangle given by $x\geq0$, $y\geq0$, and $x+y\leq1$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ such that $a,b>0$.

I can see that the vertices of the triangle are $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$. To check whether there is a maximum in the interior of the triangle, would I just check to find points where both partials vanish, or do I need to apply Lagrange multipliers? If so, what would I use for the constraint function? On the boundaries, I know to check the values at the three vertices, but what about all the other points on the boundaries?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are only used when you are forced to a constraint in the form of an equality; i.e. "maximise/minimise $f(x)$ given $g(x)=0$"" type questions. You would almost never want to try to introduce $g$ when it's not already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On two of the three boundaries, the function is just zero. On the last one, you know $x + y = 1$, so you can rewrite your function as a one-variable function

$$f(x, y) = f(x, 1 - x) = x^a e^{-x} (1 - x)^b e^{-(1 - x)} = \frac 1 e x^a (1 - x)^b$$

which isn't too hard to maximize.

Then for the interior, try to identify the critical points where $f_x = f_y = 0$.